# IllegalArgumentException: Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match For a color image

Tags: java, image-processing

I got this exception when my app is trying to read a JPG image using ImageIO.read(  ) method. This exception is not thrown for all jpg file.

I found this answer useful [Intersection of bands in R raster package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598516/intersection-of-bands-in-r-raster-package), but still it converts my colored image to a black n white one. I guess that question has focused on the right issue, but I want it to keep my image colored(not black and white).

Download image: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=19547371C4F3B839&id=19547371C4F3B839%21105

Simply if someone can obtain a BufferdImage from the image given that's enough (should not convert the image to gray scale one).

You are a genius if you can answer this :D.
Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

That is typically the exception you get when Java cannot read the JPEG file. While they are standard compliant JPEGs Java has not implemented the full standard. I recommend converting the JPEG file with ImageMagick, Irfanview, or something like this before actually trying to open it in Java.

You may use [ImageJ](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/&ei=YwzgUcS7I4n54QSN3oHYBg&usg=AFQjCNGnkzWAmC5t2IbtD4C8ayw1R0v7tg&sig2=bsgg-chtkS51amUjiXhsKw&bvm=bv.48705608,d.bGE), which can deal with most JPEGs.

Comment: Thanks Mathias for the reply. I tried this but I couldn't get a BufferedImage Object form this. It gives only ToolkitImage. And it's not possible to convert that  ToolkitImage to BufferedImage as well. So it would be great if you could suggestion a way to convert my image to a BufferdImage object. Thanks alot again.