# How do I use a list object instead of a sequence of parameters in a function call?

Tags: r

For example, if I have a list of `lm` objects, how can I pass it to the function `anova`?

I tried searching for any references to variadic functions in R, or any similar functions to the `apply` of LISP, with no success.

EDIT: I got it, this can be done via do.call, according to [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714159/how-to-wrap-a-function-that-only-takes-individual-elements-to-make-it-take-a-lis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lapply` function is your friend.  Here is a complete but nonsensical example:

```
R> set.seed(42)                      # be reproducible
R> X <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=2)
R> y <- vector(mode="list", length=3)
R> y[[1]] <- runif(50); y[[2]] <- rt(50, 3); y[[3]] <- rbinom(50, 5, 0.5)
```

At this point, we have list with candidate dependent variables, and a common set of regressors.  So let's use `lapply()` to run several regressions at once, and then again
to, say, extract coefficients.

```
R> fits <- lapply(y, FUN=function(z) { lm(z ~ X) })
R> coefs <- lapply(fits, coef)
R> coefs
[[1]]
(Intercept)          X1          X2 
  0.4543939   0.0503187   0.0442636 

[[2]]
(Intercept)          X1          X2 
  0.1115462  -0.0720639   0.1398801 

[[3]]
(Intercept)          X1          X2 
  2.3338105   0.0991485   0.0965852 

R>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However, `lapply` works like a map function, transforming each of the elements in its input list.   What I need is to pass the entire list at once to `anova` (ie: to compare models).